# Accessing instance variables across multiple c# files

Tags: c#

What is the preferred method for accessing variables that need to be instantiated across multiple C# files?

For example a dictionary cannot be declared in one file and used in another unless it is passed from method to method.

I have the same problem with an array of bytes.

I am primarily a C++ coder and these problems are handled by include files or extern declarations.

'Small' variables in C# can be global. But this option - to the best of my knowledge - is not possible with variables that need to be instantiated like dictionaries or byte arrays.

Sorry for the newbie question but I can't find any solutions in my books or on the Internet. I've already wasted a good part of today trying to figure out how to use a dictionary in two C# files in the same project without any answers.

To try and be more detailed about the problem:

This is the declaration in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static byte[,] TerrainMap;
```

But when I try to access it in another file PlantDisplay.xaml.cs (which shares the same namespace) it throws the error:  error CS0103: The name 'TerrainMap' does not exist in the current context

Comment: `For example a dictionary cannot be declared in one file and used in another unless it is passed from method to method` false. Make it `public static` and you can use it anywhere in the code.

Comment: Do you want the dictionary to be available to classes other than the one it's defined in? Or do you want one class to be split across multiple files? Classes are the logical unit I'd be thinking of, rather than files.

Comment: Wow! Really?!?!?! How about enumerated types?

Comment: Let's start with a byte array: public static byte[,] TerrainMap; It's declared in MainWindow.xaml.cs in the public partial class MainWindow : Window ... but over in PlantDisplay.xaml.cs it throws an error "PlantDisplay.xaml.cs(368,20): error CS0103: The name 'TerrainMap' does not exist in the current context" How do I resolve this?

Comment: Does it have a different namespace by any chance? If it does - you'll have to add a `using TheOtherNameSpace;` at the top of PlantDisplay.

Comment: Substitute `MainWindow.TerrainMap` instead of simply `TerrainMap`. (As in my answer)

Comment: When you're replying to a comment (as opposed to an answer) - you can start it with `@nameRepliedTo` so he will be notified.

Comment: @ispiro... Hey! That's the answer! I don't know how to flag it.. but adding the other namespace works

Comment: @zetar Flag what? If you mean delete a comment of yours - hover above the `x minutes ago` that's after your comment - and an `x` will appear.

Comment: Spoke too soon ( I wanted to flag you answer as correct)... The compiler buys it, but it's crashing at runtime because "PlantMap doesn't exist in the current context" MainWindow.PlantMap

Comment: @ispiro: Don't know if you caught the update, but the compiler is buying it but it's crashing at runtime: because "PlantMap doesn't exist in the current context" MainWindow.PlantMap. PlantMap is being instantiated in MainWindow.

Comment: Assuming you're using Visual Studio 2010 and clicking the Arrow ("Start debugging") - I don't know what might be the problem. However _sometimes_ clicking `Build -> Rebuild Solution` solves problems like this.

Comment: Um... You were talking about **Terrain** Map. Now you're getting "**Plant** Map doesn't exist in the current context"?? Perhaps **Plant** Map is a different variable (which is _not_ static)?

Comment: @ispiro: Hey, I owe you a beer (or better a tall glass of scotch). Thanks to you I got it figured out. PlantMap is an array of objects... it wasn't being instantiated correctly. Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can make your dictionary static, but that look like a poor design option. From object-oriented perspecitve, better alternative is to put the functions you need form the dictionary to a separate interface with meaningful name, like `ISettingsProvider` with GetValue/SetValue methods, and pass it to the constructors of other classes that need it.

You can also use dependency injection to wire these classes together.

Answer (score 1):

Make a class with the variable you need as static (and public).

You can later change it as you wish from anywhere. Just *declare* it as static, and "instantiate" it anywhere.

**Example**

```
class MyClass
{
    public static Dictionary<int, string> dictionary;
}
```

And anywhere:

```
MyClass.dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for *static members*:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static IDictionary<string, string> SomeAccessibleDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> 
    {
        { "dictionary", "data" },
        { "key", "value" },        
    }
}
```

This sample could be accessed with:

```
SomeClass.SomeAccessibleDictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

file myclass1.cs:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    public SomeObject SomeProperty {get;set;}
}
```

file myclass2.cs:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        var myprop = this.SomeProperty;
    }

}
```

When compiled, these 2 separate pieces of code will be compiled in a single class.

Answer (score 0):

a public static on a class can be accessed from anywhere.   C# will allow you to access any  declared type even across files.  Its different from C++ in that as long as a type exists within your project C# will be able to resolve the type name,  you don't have to #include any headers or anything.

Having said that,  accessing public static fields is often a sign of a bad design.   Sometimes they are needed  / make life easier,  but often there's a better way to do things.

Comment: I've tried that. The compiler is buying it, but when it's crashing at runtime with, "The name PlantMap does not exist in the current condition'. I'm accessing it like this:  MainWindow.PlantMap[x, y].Name = name;